# How to access and print objects of class stored in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class node():

    def __init__(self,city,distance,speed,highway):
        self.city = city
        self.distance = distance
        self.speed = speed
        self.highway = highway


file=open("testDocument.txt","r")
f1=file.read()
newdict=dict()
road_list = [lines.split() for lines in f1.split("\n")]
for line in road_list:
    firstcity=node(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])
    secondcity=node(line[0],line[2],line[3],line[4])
    newdict[line[0]] = (newdict.get(line[0], []) + [firstcity])
    newdict[line[1]] = (newdict.get(line[1], []) + [secondcity])
```

Now the values stored in the dictionary are objects, how do I access a particular object, say city or distance?

Text file has data in this form:

```
City1 City2 24 45 ME_16
City1 City3 4 45 ME_6/15/16
City1 City4 73 45 ME_6/15
City2 City5 2 45 WI_29
```

Comment: `firstcity.city` should be a city name, for example. why do you need a class? read csv to pandas dataframe instead, it is much more useful for learning.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any external frameworks or libs :/ @EPo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code has some flaws: the `road_list` will have an empty string as the last element when you split like that. Its better in my opinion to use the built-in function `lines = file.readlines()`, than you can do `road_list = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]`.

To access the elements in your dictionary you can get them by key and then accessing the desired node by index or by a regular python for loop:

```
class node():
    def __init__(self, city, distance, speed, highway):
        self.city = city
        self.distance = distance
        self.speed = speed
        self.highway = highway

file = open("testDocument.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
road_list = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]
newdict = dict()
for line in road_list:
    firstcity = node(line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4])
    secondcity = node(line[0], line[2], line[3], line[4])
    newdict[line[0]] = (newdict.get(line[0], []) + [firstcity])
    newdict[line[1]] = (newdict.get(line[1], []) + [secondcity])


def list_property(key, prop):
    result = []
    for node in newdict[key]:
        if prop == 'city':
            result += [node.city]
        if prop == 'distance':
            result += [node.distance]
        if prop == 'speed':
            result += [node.speed]
        if prop == 'highway':
            result += [node.highway]
    return result


print(list_property('City1', 'city'))
print(list_property('City1', 'speed'))
```

Output for your example file:

```
['City2', 'City3', 'City4']
['45', '45', '45']
```

Comment: Also, are you sure that you want to assign `firstcity` to the key value `line[0]`? Because the `firstcity` node was initialized with `line[1]`.

Comment: is there a way to get the speed or distance of a particular city without looping over the entire keys?

Comment: Sure, if you know the city and the corresponding index in your dict you can do:

`newdict[CityName][Index].speed`, `newdict[CityName][Index].distance`

where `CityName` and `index` are the name and index of the desired city.

Comment: I happen to know the CityName but not the index. Is there a work around for it?

Comment: Like suppose I input City1 from the user then my output should return City2,City3 and City4.

Comment: I have updated the answer with your new use case in mind. Basically, if you want the output to contain every instance of that property for a given city (a key in the dict), then you can loop over the whole list and fetch the desired property.

Comment: Thank you. Also, the distance in the dict is stored as 'str' type, is there a way to change it to 'int'?

Comment: You could do so at the time you create a node when parsing the data: `firstcity = node(line[1], int(line[2]), line[3], line[4])`

Comment: Thank you. You've been very helpful.